# DC control using MOSFET

Tags: dc-motor, mosfet-driver, push-pull

I have an example of a motor control circuit that uses MOSFETs and BJTs, but I don't really understand the operating principles or how to calculate the component values. I hope you can help me with this.

[image]

- Vcc=24 V, 2 A
- Vin=5 V

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried to simulate your circuit?

Comment: Why does the circuit include an optocoupler?  Both sides of the optocoupler are tied to ground, breaking the isolation.  Both this circuit and the one you asked about yesterday include an optocoupler that doesn't seem to be needed.

Comment: Your circuit is not going to work as effectively as an alternative circuit that doesn't use the two BJT transistors = not worth explaining. The important thing here is that you show a circuit that is viable and doesn't contain superfluous components.

Comment: In addition to the other comments, the circuit does have another potential problem. During switching both Q1 and Q2 are on at the same time and there is nothing limiting the current through them other than the PSU.

Comment: @PeterJennings What voltage would their connected bases need to be at so they are both fully on at the same time and have their current only limited by the PSU?